# Spring Boot - index.html not found by controller

Tags: spring-boot

I use SpringBoot 1.5.9 and created `src/main/resources/static/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Home</title></head>
<body><h2>Hello World!!</h2></body>
</html>
```

My simple controller is handling "/" and forwarding to index.html:

```
@Controller
    public class MyController {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home(Model model) {
            System.out.println("In MyController!!!");
            return "index";
    }}
```

However when after I run my main method from:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBoot2Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBoot2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and I point my browser to: http://localhost:8080/
I am getting:
Whitelabel Error Page-There was an unexpected error `(type=Not Found, status=404)`

But, if i try to access the page directly - it works fine:
http://localhost:8080/index.html

Based on the SpringBoot documentation the static content under `src/main/resources/static/` should be rendered.
If I create folder `src/main/resources/templates/` and put my `index.html` there, and also include spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency in my pom.xml then everything works good. However I am puzzled why this basic rendering of src/main/resources/static/index.html
is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove your `MyController` class, it should work without it

Answer (score 5):

Just found the solution: the controller MyController should specify the file extension:

```
return "index.html";
```

Comment: The only way i found to make it work without extension is adding to pom.xml thymeleaf dependency. If you add this dependency, it will work without extension.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add `viewResolver`in Spring Boot configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/403").setViewName("403");
    }    


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }    

}
```

Comment: He didn't mention `jsp` files anywhere. He even mentionned `/index.html`.

Comment: Its an old question but considering his question it seems like he is new to `spring`, So I thought to share it with him as I am sure he didn't create the `spring boot` project just for showing `html` files.